# How to ensure that rxjava methods execute in parallel, and finish?

Tags: java, rx-java2

Although I've been writing Java code for many years, I've barely done any work with RxJava, and I need to understand how to map it to expected results.  I have a lot of existing code in services I work with, but I'm not convinced they are using RxJava properly.

Note that we're using an old version of RxJava, 2.1.10.  I can't upgrade at this moment.

The following is a common pattern I see in our codebase:

```
Single<ResultType> result1 = Single.<ResultType>create(source -> {
    source.onSuccess(method1(parameters));
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
Single<ReturnType> result2 = Single.<ResultType>create(source -> {
    source.onSuccess(method2(parameters));
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

if (null != result1 && null != result2) {
```

The intent of this is that the execution of "method1" and "method2" run in parallel, and that the check for "null != result1 && null != result2" happens after both methods have finished executing. I'm thinking it's possible that neither of these intentions are being fulfilled here, but I need confirmation of that, and also how to achieve those goals properly.

Comment: Do you want to use something like `combineLatest()`? Can you add a MCVE to your question which shows, how the data should be generated and proceeded?

Comment: I don't know if I want to use "combineLatest". It's not clear to me why the details I've specified aren't enough to address the question. Execute both in parallel, and wait for both to be completed.

Comment: `(null != result1 && null != result2)` checks if methods have finished executing? I think from this code they even not start executing...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your sources are setup, you can use `combineLatest()` to wait for the result from both sources. A sample proof-of-concept code might look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Callable<Integer> c1 = new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+"|Starting first");
            Thread.sleep(1111);
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+"|finished first");
            return 42;
        }};
    Single<Integer> singleFirst = Single.fromCallable(c1).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

    Callable<Integer> c2 = new Callable<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer call() throws Exception {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+"|Starting second");
            Thread.sleep(5555);
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+"|finished second");
            return 12;
        }};
    Single<Integer> singleSecond = Single.fromCallable(c2).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
    BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> func = (a,b) -> a+b;

    ObservableSource<Integer> source1 = singleFirst.toObservable();
    ObservableSource<Integer> source2 = singleSecond.toObservable();
    Observable<Integer> resultSource = Observable.combineLatest(source1, source2, func);
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+"|All setup, wait for completion");
    resultSource.blockingSubscribe(r -> {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis()+"|Result is: "+r);
    });
}
```

This might generate the following output:

```
1589229378890|All setup, wait for completion
1589229378895|Starting second
1589229378895|Starting first
1589229380007|finished first
1589229384451|finished second
1589229384452|Result is: 54
```

As you see the `Single` subscriptions run in parallel and their values are "collected" in a `combineLatest()` call at the end.